# Android Fragment Erro

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load a fragment withing placeholder with the following code:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BlankFragment()).commit();
```

However I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried the different imports but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please assist.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

The explanation is that ordinary Fragment Manager is expecting a android.app.Fragment and you're probably giving it a support.v4.Fragment (check the import in your BlankFragment class, is it from the support library?)

Comment: is this because I am using the newer version ?

Comment: It is because you're mixing "newer" Fragment and support library fragment. You must use only one and its appropriate manager and everything that comes with it. It is recommended to almost always use support library.